# Windows Phone 7 access database

Tags: windows-phone-7

What would be the most effecient and effective way to access database from WP7? I was trying WCF Ria service, but it is such a pain to have initial setup.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

RIA Services isn't supported on the platform as yet.

I would recommend checking out Rob Tiffany's database series of posts on his blog and presentations from Mix and later talks at Tech Ed.

[Windows Phone 7 Line of Business App Dev Overview Video | Rob Tiffany](http://robtiffany.com/windows-phone-7-developer-tools/windows-phone-7-line-of-business-app-dev-the-overview-video)

[Windows Phone 7 Line of Business App Dev :: Working with an In-Memory Database | Rob Tiffany](http://robtiffany.com/windows-phone-7/windows-phone-7-line-of-business-app-dev-working-with-an-in-memory-database)

You could look at any of the many 3rd party database sources also, but be mindful of your memory footprint.

It's also quite straight forward to work directly with XML files and LINQ in isolated storage.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you mean a remote database.  Exposing your database via [OData](http://www.odata.org/) may be a good option.  There is an [OData client for WP7](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/astoriateam/archive/2010/10/28/data-services-client-for-win-phone-7-now-available.aspx).  Here's [an example](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/johnalioto/archive/2010/09/22/10066508.aspx) I wrote up, there are many others.

Comment: thanks.. do you have an article on how to apply security (e.g. x509 cert) on windows phone?